# How can I make R create a column for the date?

Tags: r, date

I recently inherited an old data set that's about ~50 years of daily data across several different sites. The previous person organized the dates into three columns, i.e. column A is year, column B is month, and column C is day. This is obviously useless for any kind of time series analysis. I would like to write a line in R that combines that into the actual day in column D. So for example if column A row 1 = 1959, column B row 1 = 3, and column C row 1 = 27, how can I make column D read 3/27/1959 and ensure this is recognized as a date? I have been completely unsuccessful thus far.

Thanks,
Jill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge three different columns into a date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334763/merge-three-different-columns-into-a-date-in-r)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Pasting parts of a date together to read in as a date object has definitely been covered on SO already, so if there's some reason why previous posts aren't working for you we'd need to see what's going on