# Year Month data frame :Time series conversion in R

Tags: r

[image]I have a 65 years weather data. Where in one column the years are mentioned and in another column Months are mentioned in numeric like 1,2,3,...I am struggling to convert it into time series data set. How can I create the dates?

Comment: Can you provide a 6 row example dataframe with 2 columns: 'year' and 'month'? Also show what else is relevant to your problem if I missed something. Edit: No images please. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I have attached the pic of the data frame..Plz have a look

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334763/merge-three-different-columns-into-a-date-in-r

Comment: There is no day column...only year and month column...Then how can I create time series?

Comment: Start with `paste0(YEAR, Month, "01", sep = "/")`

Comment: I tried in this way but still could not make it...wt$date<-as.Date(with(wt,paste0(YEAR,Month,"01",sep="/")),"%Y-%m-%d")Showing <NA> <NA>

Comment: Hey ...I'm struggling...Plz tell me how to convert YEAR and Month column into time series data

Comment: Hey Abu, please see my first comment and share data in reproducible form. That makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: Hi I am trying to attach the csv file...But can't find any option other than attaching an image.. what can I do??